# connect 3 pair of speakers to receiver

Tags: data-wiring, speakers

installed 2 speakers in kitchen, dining room, padio, total of 6 speakers, 3 pair.

have an Onkyo TX-8050 receiver that has stereo SpeakerA and SpeakerB terminals with a total of 4 channels, 2 pair.

If I buy a speaker selector that also has volume controls for each speaker pair, do I wire SpeakerA, or SpeakerB terminals to the speaker selector input? Here's the speaker selector:
http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=109&cp_id=10903&cs_id=1090307&p_id=8232&seq=1&format=2

Would I only wire 1 of the 4 Speaker Channels of the receiver to speaker selector?

thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation provided with the product?

Comment: yes, it just mentions 1 pair connected to speakerA, one pair connected to SpeakerB

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the capabilities of small appliances or electronic devices.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to calculate the intended load, etc. However, the simplest thing to do is to buy a speaker splitter. Generally, they are specifically designed to combine multiple speakers in to the load expected by your amplifier.

And the device you linked to is exactly that: "... and maintains load at 8 Ohms".

Also, I have used that particular speaker selector. It's a pretty decent device.

One thing to watch out for is that some amplifiers don't like being suddenly disconnected from all speakers. Make sure that on the switch that you never turn off all of the outputs on a particular channel if your amp is on. The Yamaha amps I usually work with have no problem with this, but I have seen lower quality devices fry.

Answer (score 0):

Your receiver has 2 *sets* of 2 channels, and same with the speaker selector. Each channel set of channels has a right and left channel.  This means 2 sets of speakers.  The selector allows you to send output to 8 channels in 4 sets of right and left channels, and the A/B buttons determine which of the inputs go to which set of output speakers.

This means that you need 8 wires (or 4 paired wires).  You would wire A right to A right, A left to A left, etc., each with a positive/negative pair.

[image]